# Magento2: How to hide header on register new account form

Tags: magento2, register

needs to create a custom login and registration template. I would like to hide the top header and leave the registration form alone.
Some solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

lazyest way : put this in your global css file

```
.customer-account-login .page-header{
  display:none!important;
}
.customer-account-login .nav-sections{
  display:none!important;
}
```

geniune way : create customer_account_login.xml in app/design/frontend/yourvendor/yourtheme/Magento_Customer/layout/

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your magento root

**/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_login.xml**

Put this code :-

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true" />
```

Other ovrride this file your custom theme like :-

**app/design/frontend/themevendor/themename/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml**

put this code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true" />
</body>
</page>
```

**Output**

[image]

Thanks.